# time change in mysql code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, time

I want to change the time format in mysql query from this:

```
e_date_s = %m/%d/%Y
e_date_e = %m/%d/%Y
```

To this:

```
e_date_s = %Y/%m/%d
e_date_e = %Y/%m/%d
```

My query is:

```
$q3 = "SELECT c_m_vin, e_date_s,e_date_e FROM core 
    JOIN event_1 ON core.c_e_token = event_1.e_1_uniek WHERE ((e_date_s <= '$date') 
    AND (e_date_e >= '$date') AND (e_date_e LIKE '%$year%') 
    AND (c_m_vin = '$res1->m_vin'))";
```

I saw options through UNIX_TIMESTAMP. Does anyone understand that?

**UPDATE**

```
$q3 = "
    SELECT c_m_vin, 
    DATE_FORMAT('e_date_s','%Y-%m-%d') AS e_date_s_new,
    DATE_FORMAT('e_date_e','%Y-%m-%d') AS e_date_e_new
    FROM core 
    JOIN event_1 
    ON core.c_e_token = event_1.e_1_uniek WHERE ((e_date_s_new <= '$date') AND (e_date_e_new >= '$date') AND (e_date_e_new LIKE '%$year%') AND (c_m_vin = '$res1->m_vin'))";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` function in your select statement to format the date directly in the query, provided your column is an actual date type.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(e_date_s, "%Y/%m/%d") AS formatted_date
from...
```

Comment: How do I process that in my query?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question there...?  This is how you would adjust the select statement that you would run in your query to return the properly formatted date.

Comment: Where do I have to place DATE_FORMAT? And after the AS is that the new name of e_date_s?

Comment: You wrap DATE_FORMAT around the column name just as I've shown. `formatted_date` would be the new name of the value. You can make that whatever you want or not use it at all. That function takes two arguments, first is the column name, then the format.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: That looks to be correct to me. although you may not need the quotes around the column names. Did it work for you?

Comment: Negative, I deleted the quots. Is it a problem that my date in my DB is m/d/Y? Maybe he can not change it.

Comment: I use now varchar, because my applicatie needs the m/d/Y date format. Is there a other solution?

Comment: Yes, never, ever, ever store dates as strings (text, varchar, etc.). No matter what, don't do that.  Always store dates as some type of date.  Do your formatting and manipulation when you retrieve it (like I've shown).  When you store dates as strings, you lose all your capability to manipulate it as a date.  Alter your column to a date format.

Comment: Ok Thx! I change everything now.